# How do I create a simple SMB file share?

Tags: applications, settings, pantheon-files, networking

I'm not interested in cloud storage or anything like that, I just need to share out a folder so that OS X and Windows clients can connect to it. Connecting to shares FROM Elementary OS seems to be built in, but I don't see any "friendly" way to share out a folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install samba server and make some edits in its config file:

`sudo apt-get install samba samba-common`

After that you have to edit the file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Just add the following (of course for requirements) to the end of the file:

```
[SharedFolder1]
   comment = My shared folder
   read only = yes
   path = /home/user/samba/shared_folder1
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
```

After that you have to (re-)start the samba server:

`sudo service samba restart`

If the samba daemon does not automatically start on system start, type the following command:

`sudo sysv-rc-conf samba on`

**Edit: For Loki and Juno (Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04) the commands are:**

`sudo systemctl start / stop smbd` for start / stop the server and `sudo systemctl enable / disable smbd` for autostart the daemon.

The displayed name in Windows will be "SharedFolder1".

**Note:** In the example above everyone has access to the folder without a password (guest ok = yes) but only in read-only mode (read-only = yes). Maybe [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html) can also help you.

Comment: now the command for restart the server is sudo service smbd restart

Comment: 'sudo sysv-rc-conf samba on' doesn't work - also needs updating.

Answer (score 0):

## Try samba GUI tool system-config-samba

### Check samba is installed

`smbd --version`

### install if required

`sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin`

### Run the following command to install it.

`sudo apt install system-config-samba`

### Then we can start it from command line.

`sudo system-config-samba`

### If you get the following error:

`` :~$ could not open configuration file `/etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory ``

### You can fix it by creating an empty /etc/libuser.conf file with the following touch command.

`sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf`

### @pblakez