# How to transfer files between Freya and Windows?

Tags: release-freya, networking, shared-libraries

I dont want to use Bluetooth.  Which i feel slow to transfer. I wan to share my files from Freya to windows. And just like we can do in Ubuntu.I need to share files through wifi or LAN. Any idea to create file sharing like we do in ubuntu and windows.

[Ubuntu windows Files Sharing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows)

Comment: have you tried that link?

Comment: actually we dont have the share this folder option in right click menu

Comment: Oops, my mistake let me try :)

Comment: Please see [this](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/how-do-i-create-a-simple-smb-file-share/3003#3003) answer. Alternatively you can share a folder on the windows pc and access it through the 'entire network' or 'connect to server' options in pantheon-files.